# Javascript regex to return number following a hyphen and a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to extract the number on the right hand side of a string split by a hyphen.

For `1 - 15` I want to return `15`.

For `0 - 8` I want to return `8`.

Bear in mind I don't want to include the white-space between the hyphen and the number.

I've tried `[^-\s]\d`, but this isn't right.

Comment: you are searching for "exactly one character that is not a `-` or a ` `, then exactly 1 digit"

Comment: why do you need a regex, anyway, why don't you simply use `str.split(" - ")[1]`?

Comment: Fair point. I've tried doing it this way because I'm trying to learn more about regular expressions. I may go with your suggested implementation though.

Comment: What is input is `"1 - 15 foo"`, then split won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [non capturing group:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

```
(?:\d+)\s-\s(\d+)
```

This one will look for:

```
(?:\d+) //a group of one or more numbers
\s      //a space
-       //a hyphen
\s      //a space
(\d+)   //a second group of one or more numbers.
```

The ?: tells it to throw the first match out and so it only returns the second match (after the hyphen).

Comment: Thanks. It seems like there is no definitive right answer, but this is a good explanation/solution.

Answer (score 1):

this pattern should also work `(\d+)\D*$` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tW9iL9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
str = '1 - 15';
var num = str.replace(/^[^-]*-\s*(\d+).*$/, '$1');
//=> 15
```

Answer (score -1):

normaly it should work.

use dollar at the end

```
[^-\s]\d$
```